How can I encode/pack four 10-bit integers into a Uint8Array(5) and then read them back in JavaScript?
I have a series of numbers that are between 0 and 1023.
And I wanted to see if I could pack them into a single Uint8Array.
And then read them back to their original values.
But I can't seem to get the logic right.
function writeInt10(arr, off, a, b, c, d)
{
    /*
        a   0, 1
        b   1, 2, 3
        c   3, 4
        d   4, 5
    */
    arr[off+0] = ((a >> 0) & 0xff); 
    arr[off+1] = ((a >> 6) & 0xf) | ((b >> 2) & 0xf);
    arr[off+2] = ((b >> 4) & 0xf) | ((c >> 4) & 0xf);
    arr[off+3] = ((c >> 2) & 0xf) | ((d >> 6) & 0xf);
    arr[off+4] = ((d >> 4) & 0xf);
}
function readInt10(arr, off) {
    var a = arr[off+0] << 0 | arr[off+1] << 2
    var b = arr[off+1] << 6 | arr[off+2] << 4
    var c = arr[off+2] << 0 | arr[off+3] << 8
    var d = arr[off+3] << 0 | arr[off+4] << 8
    
    return [a, b, c, d];
}

var buf = new Uint8Array(5);
var write = writeInt10(buf, 0, 1023, 100, 512, 768)
var read = readInt10(buf, 0)
console.log(read)


A Uint8Array(5) would be 40 bits, not 10..

@Keith I think OP wants 4 10-bit integers to be stored into a 5 element 8-bit array.

@Matthew  Yeah, that makes sense now.. :)

Yes @Matthew that is exactly what I am trying to achieve

Your 0xf masks are wrong. You'll need 0x3, 0xc, 0xf respectively:
0xff = 0b11111111
0xfc = 0b11111100
0xf0 = 0b11110000
0xc0 = 0b11000000
0x00 = 0b00000000
0x03 = 0b00000011
0x0f = 0b00001111
0x3f = 0b00001111
0x3f = 0b00111111

Also you didn't apply any bitmasks in readInt10, and I think your offsets are wrong (or I didn't understand your pattern, as you somehow spread b across 3 bytes). Here's how I'd do it:
function writeInt10(arr, off, a, b, c, d) {
    /* 0b aaaa aaaa aabb bbbb bbbb cccc cccc ccdd dddd dddd
    a: 0x    F    F    C    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 
    b: 0x    0    0    3    F    F    0    0    0    0    0 
    c: 0x    0    0    0    0    0    F    F    C    0    0
    d: 0x    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3    F    F
    */
    arr[off+0] = (a >> 2) & 0xff;                   //                    (a & 0x3fc) >> 2
    arr[off+1] = (a << 6) & 0xc0 | (b >> 4) & 0x3f; // (a & 0x003) << 6 | (b & 0x3f0) >> 4
    arr[off+2] = (b << 4) & 0xf0 | (c >> 6) & 0x0f; // (b & 0x00f) << 4 | (c & 0x3c0) >> 6
    arr[off+3] = (c << 2) & 0xfc | (d >> 8) & 0x03; // (c & 0x03f) << 2 | (d & 0x300) >> 8
    arr[off+4] = (d << 0) & 0xff;                   // (d & 0x0ff) << 0
}
function readInt10(arr, off) {
    var a = (arr[off+0] & 0xff) << 2 | (arr[off+1] & 0xc0) >> 6;
    var b = (arr[off+1] & 0x3f) << 4 | (arr[off+2] & 0xf0) >> 4;
    var c = (arr[off+2] & 0x0f) << 6 | (arr[off+3] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    var d = (arr[off+3] & 0x03) << 8 | (arr[off+4] & 0xff) >> 0;
    
    return [a, b, c, d];
}

(I've assumed most significant bit first order)


function writeInt10(arr, off, a, b, c, d) {
    arr[off+0] = (a >> 2) & 0xff;
    arr[off+1] = (a << 6) & 0xc0 | (b >> 4) & 0x3f;
    arr[off+2] = (b << 4) & 0xf0 | (c >> 6) & 0x0f;
    arr[off+3] = (c << 2) & 0xfc | (d >> 8) & 0x03;
    arr[off+4] = (d << 0) & 0xff;
}
function readInt10(arr, off) {
    var a = (arr[off+0] & 0xff) << 2 | (arr[off+1] & 0xc0) >> 6;
    var b = (arr[off+1] & 0x3f) << 4 | (arr[off+2] & 0xf0) >> 4;
    var c = (arr[off+2] & 0x0f) << 6 | (arr[off+3] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    var d = (arr[off+3] & 0x03) << 8 | (arr[off+4] & 0xff) >> 0;
    return [a, b, c, d];
}
const buf = new Uint8Array(5);
writeInt10(buf, 0, 1023, 100, 512, 768);
console.log(buf);
console.log(readInt10(buf, 0));




Thanks @Bergi. Good catch with the incorrect masks. I am able to read the first value with your code changes. I am going to keep playing around with it and try to see what else is going wrong on my read function!

This completely works @Bergi! It looks like I have a lot to learn still when it comes to bit shifting. Thank you for your help.

Done! I'm trying to learn from your example and create a new function to read/write 4, 10, 10 bits. But I can't seem to read the second number correctly. Do you have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Sorry the formatting does not seem to work so good in comments

Yeah you better ask a new question. Please also specify the desired bit layout, so that we can gauge whether the encoding or the decoding function is the problem

In order to accomplish the task it seems to be a lot simpler to collect all "excess bits" in a single element, although this makes another storage sequence:
function writeInt10(arr, off, a, b, c, d)
{
    arr[off+0] = a & 0xff
    arr[off+1] = b & 0xff
    arr[off+2] = c & 0xff
    arr[off+3] = d & 0xff
    arr[off+4] = (a & 0x300) >> 8 | (b & 0x300) >> 6 | (c & 0x300) >> 4 | (d & 0x300) >> 2
}

function readInt10(arr, off) {
    const n = arr[off+4] // for convenience
    const a = arr[off+0] | (n & 0x03) << 8
    const b = arr[off+1] | (n & 0x0c) << 6
    const c = arr[off+2] | (n & 0x30) << 4
    const d = arr[off+3] | (n & 0xc0) << 2

    return [a, b, c, d]
}

var buf = new Uint8Array(5)
var write = writeInt10(buf, 0, 1023, 100, 512, 768)
var read = readInt10(buf, 0)
console.log(read)


This works perfectly. Thank you @JeffRSon for taking the time figure this out. How interesting to use the extra storage sequence. It makes everything very neat and organized. I really appreciate it!
